# How to apply a regex replace in Python?

Tags: python, regex, pandas, replace

How is the following code splits the string 'Bolivia (Plurinational State of)' to 'Bolivia'?

```
energy.replace(regex=True, to_replace=[r'\d', r' \(([^)]+)\)'], value=r'')
```

Comment: You have said it.  Use split() function and get the first item of the list of words.  energy.split()[0]

Answer (score 0):

It *isn't*, it is returning `Bolivia)`.

There are several sites to compose and test regex's, e.g. [this one](https://regex101.com), which highlights how the expression matches to both the initial whitespace (your second `r' '` begins with one!) and then actually matches *everything up to* the closing parenthesis ')', i.e. it matches to

> (Plurinational State of

which is then replaced by `value=r''`

In summary, the `.replace()` code does not match on digits (`\d`), all it does is: Bolivia <s>(Plurinational State of</s>)  (note the remaining `)`).